Getting Unknown column ' ' in 'field list' (MySQL error code: 1054, SQLState: 42S22) using MySQL connect/C++
I am working on a beginner level C++ banking system project using MySQL data base server. In order to use a database from the server I have used Connect/C++ library from MySQL website. The main file was compiling and no linking errors, but as soon as the program executes a function which executes sql query, there is an error. I have given one of the functions code  which shows the following error statement in console:

Unknown column ' '  in 'field list' (MySQL error code: 1054, SQLState:
42S22) using MySQL connect/C++

I have used try-catch block in main() function.
void createCust(sql::Connection* con)
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout<<"Enter your first name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    std::string rand = std::to_string((std::rand() % 10000)); //generated a random number to assign acc_no to new customer
    this->account.acc_no = accIsPresent(con, rand); // assign unique account numbers


    // Create a statement
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Statement> stmt(con->createStatement());

    // query1: create a row with the first_name taken as input
    std::ostringstream query1, query2, query3, query4;
    query1 << "INSERT INTO customer (first_name) VALUES ("
        << name << ")";

    // Execute query1
    stmt->executeUpdate(query1.str());

    // query2: fetch 'id' from table customer
    query2 << "SELECT id FROM customer WHERE first_name = ' " << name <<" ' ";

    sql::ResultSet* res = stmt->executeQuery(query2.str());

    // assign customer id to cust_id
    this->cust_id = res->getInt("id");

    // add account for the new customer
    query3 << "INSERT INTO accounts(cust_id, acc_no)" << "VALUES (" << this->cust_id <<", " << this->account.acc_no <<")"; // error will show
    stmt->executeUpdate(query3.str());

    query4 << "UPDATE accounts SET bal = 0, transaction0 = 0, transaction1= 0, transaction2 = 0 WHERE acc_no = '" << this->account.acc_no << "'";
    stmt->executeUpdate(query4.str());

    this->account.balance = 0;
    std::cout << "Account created Successfully!" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Your Customer ID is " << this->cust_id << " and your Account Number is " << this->account.acc_no << std::endl;
}

I tried to check the spelling and syntax. I also re-wrote the function, but the same error message was shown. I think I am implementing the library wrong? I am trying to insert a new row when a customer is created (new customer) and then fetch his "cust_id" to store it locally for executing other sql queries.

OT: query2 << "SELECT id FROM customer WHERE first_name = ' " << name <<" ' "; I believe this will return nothing because of the space between ' and ". For example perhaps name is: John so this will be SELECT id FROM customer WHERE first_name = ' John ' notice its looking for a space character before J and one after n.

possibly not related to your problem but you shouldn't build SQL queries by concatenating strings, use prepared statements. Please show a [mre]

The problem is that you didn't put quotes around the name in the INSERT query. You wouldn't have problems like this if you used prepared statements.
sql::PreparedStatement  *prep_stmt

prep_stmt = con->prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer (first_name) VALUES (?)");
prep_stmt->setString(1, name.c_str());
prep_stmt->execute();
delete prep_stmt;

There's also no need to use the SELECT query. The function LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the ID that was assigned to the auto increment column in the last INSERT query.
And rather than use INSERT followed by UPDATE, you can put the values of the other columns in the INSERT query.
prep_stmt = con->preparedStatement("INSERT INTO accounts(cust_id, acc_no, bal, transaction0, transaction1, transaction2) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), ?, 0, 0, 0, 0)";    
prep_stmt->setString(1, this->account.acc_no.c_str());
prep_stmt->execute();
delete prep_stmt;

